# Should i always use instanceof - array of models

Tags: design-patterns

If I have an array of models that should all implement a specific interface, should I be using instanceof when looping over the models and before calling the implemented methods on each model?

Is this good/bad??

Comment: Why would you call instanceof? The whole point of polymorphism is to be able to call a method on an object without knowing and caring about its concrete type. It implements the interface, and that's all you need to know.

Comment: because they are inside an array, and elements in the array can be of different types

Comment: They're all of the same type: the interface they all implement. In a Foo[] array, every element is a Foo. Some might be instances of FooImpl1, and some other of FooImpl2, but they're all Foo. And that's all you need to know to call a method declared in Foo.

Comment: Not in my situation.  The language allows arrays to be made up of anything i.e. array(1, '1', new MyObject()) is valid

Comment: You said: *If I have an array of models that should all implement a specific interface*. If they all implement a specific interface Foo, they should be in an array of type Foo[], not in an array of type Object[]. Why don't you post your code? It would be easier to give advice if we saw he code, instead of guessing what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

For god sake! NEVER!

You already have that interface with method you need, you dont want to instanceof them, there is no reason for it. In fact, there is (almost) never ever reason to use instanceof :D.

Comment: I mean i agree that `instanceOf` usage should be discouraged but there are specific situations where it becomes necessary to use it like if you receive an object from an external source, it could be on network or read from disk, to know the type of that object at runtime, the `instanceOf` should be used.

Comment: I am asking specifically in a situation where the objects are elements of an array.  The array can have different elements of different types so when looping over them how can i know it is safe to call the interface methods

Comment: I agree with @MartyWallace One might need to know the instanceOf if the one is not sure of the typeof elements in array

Answer (score 0):

> Is this good/bad??

Not good :) But if you have only one array, you have no other way. But I'd suggest to implement a storage with a number of different arrays encapsulated:

```
public class Field {
    private Shape[] shapes = ...
    private Circle[] circles = ...
    private Rectangle[] rectangles = ...

    public void addCircle(Circle c) {
        shapes[...] = c;
        circles[...] = c;
    }

    public Shape[] getShapes() {
        return shapes;
    }

    public Circle[] getCircles() {
        return circles;
    }

}

...

field.getShapes(n).draw(); // for both Circle and Rectangle available

int radius = field.getCircles(m).getRadius()); // for Circle only
```